# Call different jQuery functions depending on suffix in their name

Tags: jquery

I have 3 jQuery functions with indexed progressive name such as:

```
function foo_1()
{
   ...
}

function foo_2()
{
   ...
}

function foo_3()
{
   ...
}
```

I need to dynamically discern the functions as shown:

```
foo_[i]
```

The overall purpose is to call a different function depending on the value of `i` variable.

How should I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for example:

```
var i = "3";
window["foo_" + i]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the plain Javascript method `eval()`:

```
var index = 1;
eval("foo_"+index+"()");
```